# Contact Form 7: Drop-Down Menu with Read-Only Values?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

Hi – is it possible to create a **Contact 7 Form** Drop-down Menu with ‘Read-Only’ values ?

[image: Screenshot - Read ONLY Entries ( Red Box)]

**Syntax Example**

```
[select* trifold-template include_blank "Trifold #1" "Trifold #2" "Trifold #3"]
```

Is it possible to incorporate ‘Read-Only’ values’into syntax code above ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Contact form 7, we still have no option for the same.
I suggest you to check some other plugin.
If you want this in html code, you can check here : https://codepen.io/adrian-ortega/pen/Ivzjh